# When I connect my smartphone to the Android studio emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I connect my smartphone to the Android studio emulator,
Can't the screen of the app connected to my smartphone appear on the pc monitor like when I used the Android studio virtual emulator?

please...

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio does not have the functionality to display the screen of a connected device on a PC.

You can use the 3rd-party command line tool [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) for this